# attr_accessor on singleton objects not working as expected

Tags: ruby

Why does `Cat.new.name` work but `Dog.new.name` does not work,  given these two different implementations:

```
class Cat
end 

Cat.instance_eval do
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

But this does not work:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    attr_accessor :name
  end
end
```

**Note:** I am aware that `Dog.name` *would* work, but I would think that both of these implementations would both result in creating `name` and `name=` methods for all the instantiations of `Dog` and `Cat`.

---

**Background of question:**

To start off: take the following code for example:

```
class Cat
end

Cat.instance_eval do
  attr_accessor :name
end

c = Cat.new
c.name = 'some cat name'
p c.name # => "some cat name"
```

In regards to the [ruby documentation of instance_eval](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval), I would talk through that `instance_eval` block with the following:

- We are in the context of `Cat` (`Cat` is `self`), so in essence, we are calling `Cat.attr_accessor :name`, which is a macro that is saying "Hey, for all instances created from `Cat`, give them the methods `name` and `name=`.

I am trying to extend this understanding to the following, but it is erroring out:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    attr_accessor :name
  end
end

d = Dog.new
d.name = "dog name" # => undefined method `name=' for #<Dog:0x007ff6c3062c20> (NoMethodError)
```

Talking through this, I would say `class << self` is saying:

- put me in the context of the singleton object of `Dog`, so `self`is now that singleton object of `Dog`
- call the `attr_accessor` macro on that singleton object of `Dog` (so we are really calling `<singleton_of_Dog>.attr_accessor :name`). Now every time we instantiate a `Dog` object, each of those dog objects now has `name` and `name=`.

The error is clearly stating that my thinking is incorrect here, but I am not sure what part I am missing.

I have searched previous stack overflow questions, read books and watched videos explaining the ruby object model.  Nevertheless, there are clearly some foundational concepts that I have not entirely grasped.

Comment: What is your question? `Dog.name` would perfectly work, since you declare an accessor on the class level. `Dog.new.name` obviously does not work because instances of `Dog` were not granted with accessors.

Comment: "put me in the context of the singleton object of Dog" - here's where you're wrong. It puts you in the context of the singleton _class_ of Dog. Of which class there's only one instance, `Dog`. And attr_accessor grants getter/setter to this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical usage for `class << self` is to make a block where instance methods get defined as class methods. This lets you skip typing the `self.` in the method definition and also makes other facilities available like private/protected.

How this works is by opening up Dog's singleton class and adding instance methods to it. Instance methods of Dog's singleton class become class methods on Dog. This is just part of the definition of singleton classes.

In the case of attr_accessor, that's a method you call in the class scope of Dog, and which defines instance methods on Dog.

When you call attr_accessor on Dog's singleton class, it creates instance methods on Dog's singleton class. Instance methods of Dog's singleton class become class methods on Dog. That's why you can use `Dog.name =` and not `Dog.new.name =` with your code.